# How to write maxLik results in a .csv file or .txt file in R? Is there a way?

Tags: r, export

I am using maxLik function of R maxLik package to estimate MLE. I would like to save the results in a csv or txt file to be able to compare the different models. I tried the following:

```
par <- c(0.97, -0.74, -3.43, -6.26, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
a <- maxLik (logLik, start = par, method = "BFGS", dat = nParams, nV = nVeh) 
b <- summary(a)
write.table (b, "Model2_Estimation.txt")
write.csv (b, "Model2_Estimation.csv")
```

However, it gives me error that object type is not writeable. I am not sure what it means exactly. Is that a way to export the mle results to excel or text file? Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: You cant use write.table on b as  the object to be written to file has to be a matrix or a dataframe. see`?write.table`. If you want the estimates you can use `write.table (b$estimate, "Model2_Estimation.txt")` or if you want what is printed to the screen use`cat (capture.output(b), file="Model2_Estimation.txt", sep="\n")`

Comment: `write.table` writes a table. If you read the documentation, you'll see that the input object is a `data.frame` or `matrix`... Though my real question is **why?** What is the purpose of exporting this to excel or text? There is no reason why you cannot compare the MLE of various models **within R**. In fact, I would argue that trying to do so in excel is *harder* not *easier*

Comment: @user20650 Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I hit my head to the wall that I never thought of just using estimates!

Comment: @Alex I would like to have the estimates and likelihood for the future references in my archive as I will have a lot of models estimated. I will not be doing calculations in Excel at all. Thanks for taking time!

Comment: You can save the models in a *.Rdata file... just my personal preference.

Comment: For your "reference", you may just save the text output of `summary(a)`.  If you want to save some sort of table, you may save `coef(summary(a))`.  This is a matrix (coef, std.dev, t, Pr) you an use as data frame.  `summary(a)` itself is a complex object that cannot easily be transformed to a data frame.  Otherwise, just `save(a, file="a.Rdat")` is a good choice, as suggested above.